# OpenCV LDFlags linking issue

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv

I am compiling a program with the following flags and getting errors (running 64 bit os):

```
g++ -lm -lml -lcvaux -lhighgui -lcv -lcxcore main.o BRIEF.o -o BRIEF_demo
```

I get a bunch of undefined references:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f6): undefined reference to `cvInitMatHeader'
```

main.cpp:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `cvInitMatHeader'
main.o: In function`_Z14drawQuadrangleP9_IplImageiiiiiiii8CvScalari.constprop.77':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d5): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x333): undefined reference to`cvLine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x398): undefined reference to `cvLine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3f2): undefined reference to`cvLine'

Anyone have an idea how to circumvent this?

Comment: Have you compiled the code where cvInitMatHeader is defined?

Comment: It is in the libraries I am specifying with the -l option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using the newest OpenCV 2.3.x.  `cvInitMatHeader()` and `cvLine()` are actually defined in `libcxcore.so`, which I can see you are including.

My guess is that the order of the linking is wrong, so you need to adjust your command to something like:

```
g++ main.cpp BRIEF.cpp -o BRIEF_demo -lm -lml -lcvaux -lhighgui -lcv -lcxcore
```